# Pickadate is not a function. Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, pickadate

This is my first time in SO. My concern is that I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).pickadate is not a function
```

error in the console.

Before that, I was able to include the files (picker.js, picker.date.js, picker.time.js) detected in the Javascript [F12 in Chrome].

Here are the other codes:

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="pure-control-group">
    <%= t.label :start_date %>
    <%= t.text_field :start_date, class: 'datepicker' %>
</div>
```

application.js

```
//= require_self
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require angular
//= require angular-animate
//= require angular-resource


//= require picker
//= require picker.date
//= require picker.time
//= require globals
//= require users
```

globals.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('p').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });

    $('.datepicker').pickadate();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, such an issue was caused by the jquery I was using or lack thereof. I had to install jquery using yarn:

```
yarn add jquery
```

Once done, it should be included in your `node_modules` folder. Confirm you have the following line in your `config/initializers/assets.rb`:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')
```

You can then include jquery in your `assets/application.js` like so:

```
//= require jquery/dist/jquery
```

For some reason, I couldn't get the `jquery-rails` package.
You can find a related resource with more detailed instructions [here](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/yarn-rails/), though it is one used to install bootstrap on rails, it holds the same concept for rails.

Also, make sure you have `pickadate-rails` gem in your Gemfile and you have run `$ bundle install`. Retain these changes in your `application.js`

```
//= require picker
//= require picker.date
//= require picker.time
```

Restart your server too after making the changes.

For more info on how to implement jquery-rails on rails, check this link out:
https://medium.com/@chantaljustamond/implementing-pickadate-js-on-a-rails-app-c47af58c33af

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('p').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });

    $('.datepicker').pickadate(
    selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
    selectYears: 3 // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
  });
);

});
```

or if i didnt solve your problem then you can try the rails way that is adding gem in gemfile and then run the command. the best gem for pickadate is [pickadate-rails](https://github.com/veracross/pickadate-rails)

Comment: Sorry but it's not working for me. I also had pickadate-rails gem. :(